# SQL Crawl Hierarchy - Get All Relationships

Tags: sql, loops, recursion, hierarchy, recursive-query

I think this will be easier to explain as a story instead of sample code.

- I have a table of Parents and Children.
- A Parent could be the Child of another Parent, and so on.
- There are top Level Parents.
- Siblings are possible (2 or more Children of same Parent)

I am trying to crawl this table in SQL and get all relationships.

Below is an bulleted example of how the relationships would work.

```
o 6220 (Top Level Parent)
    - 6219 (Child1 of 6220)
    - 6221 (Child2 of 6220)
       * 6222 (Child1 of 6221/GrandChild1 of 6220)    
       * 6223 (Child2 of 6221/GrandChild2 of 6220)
           x 6224 (Child1 of 6223/GrandChild1 of 6221/GreatGrandChild1 of 6220)
o 6225 (Top Level Parent)
```

Here is how it looks in table form:

```
Parent, Child
NULL,    6220
6220,    6221
6220,    6219
6221,    6222
6221,    6223
6223,    6224
NULL,    6225
```

The result I am looking for (optimally) is:

```
Parent, Child, Level
6220,    6220,   0
6220,    6221,   1
6220,    6219,   1
6220,    6222,   2
6220,    6223,   2
6220,    6224,   4
6221,    6222,   1
6221,    6223,   1
6221,    6224,   2
6223,    6224,   1
6225,    6225,   0
```

I've tried recursive CTE's and Loops, and I can get close, but not quite.  Looking to get close to this or something similar that makes sense.  I want to put this into a table that I can query to find all parents, grandparents, children, grandchildren, etc of a parent or child.  Sibling relationships aren't important.

Thanks for looking.  Please let me know if I can clarify.

Here's how I had been trying to do this:

```
    DECLARE @InsertedCount INT
DECLARE @RelationshipLevel TINYINT 
DECLARE @AgyCount INT 
DECLARE @LoopCount INT = 1
DECLARE @AgencyId INT

SELECT @AgyCount = COUNT(AgencyId) FROM dbo.Agency AS A


/* ==============================================================================
    Get All AgencyIDs into a table with an incremented column
============================================================================== */

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmpAllAgy') > 0)
    DROP TABLE #tmpAllAgy

CREATE TABLE #tmpAllAgy (tmpAllAgyId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, AgencyId INT)

INSERT INTO #tmpAllAgy (AgencyId)
SELECT AgencyId FROM dbo.Agency ORDER BY AgencyId


/* ==============================================================================
    Temp table for the results of the matrix to compare to physical table
============================================================================== */
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#ChildAgencies') > 0)
        DROP TABLE #ChildAgencies

CREATE TABLE #ChildAgencies (LoopOrder INT, ParentAgencyId INT, ChildAgencyId INT,          RelationshipLevel TINYINT)

/* ==============================================================================
    Outer loop to get the next Agency Id from Temp Table
============================================================================== */

WHILE @LoopCount <= @AgyCount

BEGIN

    SET @RelationshipLevel = 0  

    SELECT @AgencyId = AgencyId FROM #tmpAllAgy WHERE tmpAllAgyId = @LoopCount  

    INSERT INTO #ChildAgencies(LoopOrder, ParentAgencyId, ChildAgencyId, RelationshipLevel)
    SELECT @LoopCount, NULL, AgencyId, @RelationshipLevel   
    FROM dbo.Agency
    WHERE AgencyId = @AgencyID

    SET @InsertedCount = 1--@@ROWCOUNT


/* ==============================================================================
    Inner loop to create the hierarchy for each AgencyId
============================================================================== */

WHILE @InsertedCount > 0
BEGIN

    SET @InsertedCount = NULL
    SET @RelationshipLevel = @RelationshipLevel + 1      

    INSERT INTO #ChildAgencies (LoopOrder, ParentAgencyId, ChildAgencyId, RelationshipLevel)
    SELECT @LoopCount, @AgencyId, AgencyId, @RelationshipLevel  
    FROM dbo.Agency
    WHERE AgencyId NOT IN (SELECT ChildAgencyId FROM #ChildAgencies)
        AND ParentAgencyId IN (SELECT ChildAgencyId FROM #ChildAgencies)
        AND StatusCode <> 109 /*QA-Deleted*/

    SET @InsertedCount = @@ROWCOUNT

END

    SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
END
```

A recursive CTE seems to only bring direct parents and children, while incrementing the count arbitrarily.
The above looping code, is close, but seems to do things in a weird order.

Comment: The "LoopOrder" in the sample code was just for troubleshooting.  I was verifying the order the loop was looping.  As a field, it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally got something to work.  It's almost the same thing as I had been doing.  Instead of the loop in a loop, I took the inner loop and made it a function.  Then I created a SP that loops, and feeds the function an ID at a time and appends the results to a temp table.

Here is basically the inner loop:

```
DECLARE @AgencyId INT = 6220
DECLARE @InsertedCount INT
DECLARE @LevelCount INT = 0


CREATE TABLE #ChildAgencies(AgencyId INT, LevelCount INT)


INSERT INTO #ChildAgencies(AgencyId, LevelCount)
SELECT AgencyId, @LevelCount    
FROM dbo.Agency
WHERE AgencyId = @AgencyId

SET @InsertedCount = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE @InsertedCount > 0
BEGIN

    SET @InsertedCount = NULL
    SET @LevelCount = @LevelCount + 1      

    INSERT INTO #ChildAgencies(AgencyId, LevelCount)
    SELECT AgencyId, @LevelCount    
    FROM dbo.Agency
    WHERE AgencyId NOT IN (SELECT AgencyId FROM #ChildAgencies)
        AND ParentAgencyId IN (SELECT AgencyId FROM #ChildAgencies)
        AND StatusCode <> 109 /*QA-Deleted*/

    SET @InsertedCount = @@ROWCOUNT

END
```

Which produces:

```
AgencyId    LevelCount
6220              0
6219                1
6221                1
6222                2
6223                2
6224                3
```

Obviously, I don't have the @AgencyId variable defaulted in the final product.  I set @AgencyId in the stored procedure and pass it to this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are proposing is not possible using a SQL query.  It is theoretically possible that your relationships have cycles.  You are basically implementing graphs in a SQL table, since siblings are possible.  Let's say that 6221 is parent of 6222, 6222 is parent of 6223, and 6223 is parent of 6221?  Then you have a cycle.

If such a structure is guaranteed not to exist, then you still have a fully connected graph to deal with in the worst case.  Is there a maximum "age difference"?  If so, then you can just make a finite number of joins to do this, using outer joins to insure those without a relationship still get included.  For each "level" of the relationship, you have to perform three joins: one for the parent, one for the siblings, and one for the children.  You also need to make sure you don't traverse back into your original node.

In short, assuming no cycles, you are implementing tree traversal in a table containing a forest of trees.  I don't know how you could do this in SQL.  You could do it in a programming language, or perhaps as a stored procedure using loops, but only if there are no cycles, or you implement cycle detection in some way.

Best of luck.

Edit: Also, unless you are given the tree roots (top level nodes) any node in a tree can be considered a root.  If the base graph is a directed graph, however (parent-child relationship is explicit) then a root is a node with no parent.  For an N-Ary tree with a defined root and finite depth, you could implement any standard graph search algorithm with a traversal cost of 1, until all nodes have a cost associated with them.  There's breadth-first search, depth-frist search, best-first search, A*, etc.

Edit:
Try something like this:

```
create procedure update_node_depths
as
begin
    set nocount on

    update nodes
    set depth = null

    update nodes
    set depth = 0
    where parent_id is null

    while exists (select node_id from nodes where depth is null)
    begin
        update nodes
        set depth = (select n2.depth+1
                     from nodes n2
                     where n2.node_id = nodes.parent_id)
        where parent_id in (select node_id
                            from nodes n3
                            where n3.depth is not null)
     end

     select * 
     from nodes
end
go
```

You can then do something like this to get your table, automatically updating depths when you do so.

```
execute update_node_depths
go
```

Comment: The sibling relationships don't matter, as long as both siblings show up under their respective parents and grand-parents.  It is like a family tree, but the relationships I'm interested in are only straight up and down.

Comment: In that case, you are traversing an N-Ary tree, and looking for the depth.  You still have to run a query and/or create outer joins for n levels, where n is the maximum depth.  You could do it programmatically (outside SQL or using a stored procedure) by setting the level of each node.  First, set the level of the top level parents.  Then set the level of all nodes to 1 + the level of the parent for all nodes whose parents have a level, end when all nodes have levels assigned, and return the resulting set of tuples of nodes, parents, and levels.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit hard to understand at start but all you need is trying more.
I got a example from MSDN

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

And managed to do it working ad SQLFiddle, just removed some "fat"

Hope it ill help you

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1438/17

Comment: Note: It would be good to get the basic query you're using here, in case the fiddle ever gets lost...  Also, this would only work with SQL Server of course.

Comment: Note: A minor modification would be COALESCE(e.ManagerID, 1) so for the first level since the ManagerId is null the value would be 1 which is same as the employeeId.

Comment: When I go to the SQL Fiddle link, it seems to take me to a "create a new fiddle" page.

Comment: When I use the recursive CTE like the one in the SQLFiddle, It only returns direct children and parents, but increments the level.
For instance it gave me 6223,6224,3 instead of 6220,6224,3.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the base case: someone with a `Parent` value of `NULL` will *always* have a `Level` of `0`. This means you can update every row where `Parent is NULL` and set `Level = 0`.

Next step: Find the rows who have parents who have a `Level` value that is `not NULL`. Update them to have a `Level` value = `parent.Level + 1`.

Repeat the above step until every row of your table has a `Level` value.